# Mysql can't create user / grant privileges on existing ones (access denied)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

After installing Mysql through apt-get on Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS and messing around with it I'm in the position where I have no account that can do any operation to grant privileges or create a new user.

I can only connect to it via

> mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf

```
select host,user ,select_priv, Create_user_priv from mysql.user;
```

returns the following table:

```
+-----------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
| host      | user             | select_priv | Create_user_priv |
+-----------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
| localhost | apsc             | N           | N                |
| localhost | pma_GSn1wBscFLp0 | N           | N                |
| localhost | pp_sb_db         | N           | N                |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint | Y           | Y                |
| localhost | admin            | N           | N                |
| localhost | pma_FoXErUK90AbF | N           | N                |
+-----------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

How can I create a root-user with all privileges? A full reset would be fine by me.

Commands like the following one only return `access denied` errors

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: Odd that you don't already have a root, but it looks like you'll need to log in as debian-sys-maint.

Comment: I don't know the password to that one :/